# how to display 30 mins Time Interval count in SQL Server v17.3

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server v17.3 and table is displaying below result.

```
RegisteredDateTime         TotalRegistered
2020-02-17 12:00:00.000       10
2020-02-17 15:30:00.000       25
2020-02-17 17:10:00.000       50
2020-02-17 18:15:10.000       60
2020-02-17 18:20:00.000       70
```

I would like to display total count of TotalRegistered result along with 30 mins of interval from @StartDate = '2020-02-17 09:00:00' to @EndDate = '2020-02-17 20:00:00'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Desired results would be helpful.

Comment: **can anyone help me for my question**

Comment: Can you add a **tag** for the database you're using, as you were asked to do, along with the output you want to get instead? It would also help if you posted your SQL statement to show what you've tried so far that isn't working.